# Robot Detection on Form submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 9.0.2, I am using a custom `Update Contact` submit action in forms to update facet in xDB. Now before updating contact in xDB, I want to check that if user is `Robot` or not, so for that I have checked `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.Robots` processor, it is using `ContactClassification.IsRobot` function and passing if `args.Session.Contact.System.Classification` parameter. Below is code:

```
public class Robots : CommitSessionProcessor
{
    public override void Process(CommitSessionPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        Assert.IsNotNull(args.Session.Contact, "args.Context.Contact should not be null");
        if (ContactClassification.IsRobot(args.Session.Contact.System.Classification) && AnalyticsSettings.Robots.IgnoreRobots)
        {
            ContactManager expr_58 = Assert.ResultNotNull<ContactManager>(Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager);
            expr_58.SaveContactToCollectionDb(args.Session.Contact);
            expr_58.RemoveFromSession(args.Session.Contact.ContactId);
            Log.Debug("[Analytics]: The CommitSession pipeline was aborted. Visit was classified as robot and visits made by robots are configured to be ignored.", this);
            args.AbortPipeline();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.Robots, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Database.config"/>
```

I am trying to use same function on `UpdateContact` but I am not sure what parameter I need to pass in `IsRobot` function. Below is my submit action:

```
public class UpdateContact : SubmitActionBase<UpdateContactData>
{

    public UpdateContact(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
    {
    }

    protected override bool Execute(UpdateContactData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Can anybody suggest me what parameter I need to pass instead of `args.Session.Contact.System.Classification`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to send the `Classification` stored on the current `Contact`, but how you get it is a little different:

```
if (Tracker.Current?.Session?.Contact?.System != null)
{
    ContactClassification.IsRobot(Tracker.Current.Session.Contact.System.Classification)
}
```

This will get the current session's contact and use that classification.

#### Further reading: how a visitor is classified as a robot

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/robot-detection-overview.html

Comment: Thanks dan.I will try this solution

Comment: Do you know how Sitecore identify that current contact is Robot or not?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/robot-detection.html